# Selecting a random element from an array and displaying it on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I am trying to select a random element from an array and display it using jQuery. So far I can only click through the array and reset back to 0. Not sure how to use the Math.random(); exactly here.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/Travo100/pen/xAKji

```
counter = 0;

var compArray = [ "Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit", "Cow", "Sheep", "Human" ];

$('a').click(function () {

    counter = (counter + 1) % compArray.length;
    $(this).html(compArray[counter]);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var rand = compArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * compArray.length)];
```